# Create Templates folder in Windows 7 profile

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, folder-redirection

I'd like to create a Templates folder in my profile on Windows 7, but there's already a junction to `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates`. I assume this is a system configuration so I don't want to delete it.  I'm currently calling my folder File Templates, but that seems to verbose to me. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

That folder is completely empty on my system.

Just delete the junction.